# how to print() a command once

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using these commands I get the word "Hello" printed several times

```
one=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("any")
for two in one:
    if two.text=='three'
        print('Hello') 
    else:
        print('Bye')
```

How do I change the code so that if all the elements == "three" are printed once "Hi", and if there is an element that! = "Three", it was printed once "Bye"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It‘s more clear if you use `all()` instead of `any()`:

```
one=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("any")
if all(two.text == 'three' for two in one):
    print('Hello')
else:
    print('Bye')
```

Comment: Your version prints "Bye" or "Hello" many times. I only need to once

Comment: @keepomen See my edited solution. You don‘t need the `for two in one:` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You could make `one` a set and compare the results

```
one = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("any")
two = {_.text for _ in one}
if len(two) == 1 and two[0] == 'three':
    print('hi')
else:
    print('bye')
```

Effectively this takes `('three', 'three', 'three')` and turns it into `{'three'}` or takes `('three', 'three', 'not three')` and turns it into `{'three', 'not three'}`. Then you see if it's only one element long and that element is `'three'` or not.

Hope if this explanation was needed, it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `any()`

```
one = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("any")
if any(two.text != 'three' for two in one):
    print('Bye')
else:
    print('Hello')
```

Comment: Boom, I'm always forgetting about `any`. Takes my answer to the next level

Comment: I made an edit to my question to lose the comprehension on accident because I forgot that we needed the text attribute. I deleted my comment as I realized that after I found my mistake. Still nice answer!

Comment: your version prints "Bye" or "Hello" many times. I only need to once.

Comment: @keepomen Tested it again, it prints only once.

Comment: @Guy screenshot http://joxi.ru/82QvDGlcjlnBgA Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @keepomen Delete the `for` loop, the loop is inside `any` https://trinket.io/python/74ac6a8250

Comment: @keepomen I added `driver.find` to the answer so you can see the location.

Comment: your option also works, but I like it better with if `all(two.text...`

Answer (score 0):

A function could do this:

```
one=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("any")
def helloBye(one):
    for two in one:
        if two.text!="three":
            print("Bye")
            return
    print("Hello")
    return
helloBye(one)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't understand your question before, this should do:

```
 one=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("any")
    i = 0
    for two in one:
        if two.text=='three' 
            i = i + 1
            if and i==len(one)
                 print('Hello') 
        else:
            print('Bye')
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in various ways:

Here I'm giving you two ways to do it.

1st and the easiest way is to maintain a counter and check for the counter. This can be achieved as below:

```
counter_three = 0
counter_not_three = 0
for two in one:
    if two.text=='three':
        if counter_three == 0:
            counter_three = counter_three + 1
            print('Hello') 
    else:
        if counter_not_three == 0:
            print('Bye')
            counter_not_three = counter_not_three + 1
```

2nd way is as below:

```
a = [{"text": "three"},{"text": "three"}, {"text": "three"}, {"text": "three"}, {"text": "two"}]
a_list = set(map(lambda x: x["text"], a))
for x in a_set:
    if x == 'three':
        print('Hello')
    else:
        print('Bye')
```